# Rail3 to Rails 4; changing conditions to where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, models

When upgrading to Rail4, I changed conditions to where in the model but I'm now getting a syntax error ( syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end)

```
has_many :businesses, through: :business_admins, { where business_admins: { state: 'accepted'} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
has_many :businesses, 
  -> { where(business_admins: { state: 'accepted'}) }, 
  through: :business_admins
```

Also see the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many-where).